# How to send $_GET and $_POST cookies on the same page

Tags: php, cookies

I have the below $_POST cookies that are comming from a search form

```
$In= $_POST['In'];
$Out= $_POST['Out'];
$City= $_POST['City'];
$Adults= $_GET["Adults"];
$RoomsNO= $_GET["RoomsNO"];
$Childs= $_GET["Childs"];
```

And i want to send the same cookies over $_GET from a link

```
$In= $_GET['In'];
$Out= $_GET['Out'];
$City= $_GET['City'];
$Adults= $_GET["Adults"];
$RoomsNO= $_GET["RoomsNO"];
$Childs= $_GET["Childs"];
```

Answer:
On the response page $_REQUEST has done the job.

Thanks

Comment: You can use both GET and POST in the same request. If that is what you are asking...

Comment: Change the form method to get!

Comment: Use `$_REQUEST` - they are all in there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Then  how would you differentiate $_POST['City'] and  $_GET['City']

Comment: Why would you need to @IndraKumarS?

Comment: see my answer which avoids using $_REQUEST due to the parameter names being the same in this case

Comment: @JayBlanchard He wants to get both... One through Get and another Post

Comment: That just seems like a bad idea, doesn't it?

Comment: Thats true... But He might have some strange ideas? Who knows

Comment: @JayBlanchard, The $_REQUEST 'super global' is an 'array merge' of the other arrays depending on this setting: [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) in the 'php.ini' file. Therefore 'same names' will be  'clobbered' by the last array in the list that has the value.

Comment: Please don't use $_REQUEST. Look at the other answers.

Comment: I wanted to use both,1. i use the $_post from a search field ( the values are chosen by user, he can chose city, chein check out and other values) and i use $_GET on a link with defined values ( ex: Paris link will show only results from Paris with a checkin checkout and the other data defined by me )

Answer (score 3):

So, to be clear, those aren't cookies. Those are form parameters. $_GET parses the variables out from the URL (right of the "?") because that's where those are passed. $_POST parses them out of the request body, because that's where those are passed. You can't form POST and GET at the same time (only one action is allowed from a form tag); however, you CAN do the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://yourapihere.com?foo=12345">

    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="67890">

</form>
```

The $_GET['foo'] should be 12345. and the $_POST['foo'] should be 67890. Verified using [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) and [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both GET and POST requests can be used simultaneously.

For example, if your page is on the URL `http://www.example.com/search?city=manchester` and you POST a form to that URL containing the form field named `city` with the value `chicago` then you could do the following in PHP:

```
<?php
         echo $_GET['city'].' / '.$_POST['city'];
?>
```

which will output:

```
manchester / chicago
```